# Length of data returned from CGImageGetDataProvider is larger than expected

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, image, cgimage

I'm loading a grayscale png image and I want to access the underlying pixel data. However after I load get the pixel data via CGImageGetDataProvider, the length of the data returned is longer than expected.

```
CCGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(cStr);
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, FALSE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

mapWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image);
mapHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image);

lookupMap = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image));
```

mapWidth comes out to 1804 and
mapHeight comes out to 1005. The product of which is 1813020

When I call

```
CFDataGetLength(lookupMap)
```

the response is 1833120.

Where are these extra 20100 bytes coming from?
Any help here is much appreciated. Am I missing something about the underlying format of the image?

Upon further examination of the CFDataRef I found that if I loop through the buffer,
for each row bytes: 0 to 1803 will be correct from my image, and then the next 20 bytes are all zero.  So this means that my returned image is actually coming back as a 1824 by 1005 image instead of 1804 by 1005.  Still no explanation as to why.

Answer (score 3):

There's a buffer being added to the end of each one of my rows.
I started using

```
CGImageGetBytesPerRow
```

and solved the mystery.